# How to make intellisense work for my modules using TypeScript in VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm building an application using nodejs and electron in VSCode.

I use javascript currently but I'd like to switch to typescript for better code validation and intellisense.

Intellisense is working fine for external modules (electron, lodash, node core modules) but I can't make it work with my own modules.

I have added my modules (I just show one of them in the following code) as dependencies in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "renderer-rpc": "file:local_modules/renderer-rpc",
    ...
  }
```

This is the content of renderer-rpc.ts (just the relevant code):

```
import {ipcMain} from 'electron'
import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron'


export const mainRpc = {
    init : function () {
        ...
    }
}

export const rendererRpc = {

    init : function (options) {
        ...
    },

    call : function (recipient, method, ...args) {
        ...
    },

    makeRemote: function (object, recipient) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in my main.ts (located in the root of the project) I do the following:

```
import {mainRpc} from 'renderer-rpc'

mainRpc.
```

and I don't get any suggestion from my module. Neither pressing CTRL+SPACE.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "image-gallery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Mic",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.5.1",
    "DAL": "file:local_modules/DAL",
    "async-parallel": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "db-layer": "file:local_modules/db-layer",
    "electron-pug": "^1.5.1",
    "jimp": "^0.2.28",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "renderer-rpc": "file:local_modules/renderer-rpc",
    "scattered-store": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.7.9",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "mock-require": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what's your tsconfig, package.json to specify typings for your module?

Comment: @OJKwon: I added both tsconfig and package json to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your tsconfig in the "renderer-rpc" package:

```
"declaration": true,
```

This will enforce the typescript compiler to create declaration (.d.ts) files as well during compilation.

One more thing, in "renderer-rpc", you should add this into your package.json (modify the path to point to your main typings file):

```
 "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts"
```

Comment: Thank you! I already tried with the declaration option in tsconfig but I was missing typings in each module package.json!